# Gaussian state space forecasting with regression effects

Tags: r, forecasting, dlm

The R package [dlm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/index.html) implements filtering and smoothing (`dlmFilter` and `dlmSmooth`) for models with regression effects, but forecasting is not (yet) available for these models:

```
mod <- dlmModSeas(4)+dlmModReg(cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100)))
fi <- dlmFilter(rnorm(100),mod)
f <- dlmForecast(fi,nAhead=12)
Error in dlmForecast(fi, nAhead = 12): 
  dlmForecast only works with constant models
```

How can I do this in R?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with: The trick is to add NAs to the end of the observation data. When seeing NA as a response variable the Kalman filter algorithm will simply predict the next value and not update the state vector. This is exactly what we want to make our forecast.

```
nAhead <- 12
mod <- dlmModSeas(4)+dlmModReg(cbind(rnorm(100+nAhead),rnorm(100+nAhead)))
fi <- dlmFilter(c(rnorm(100),rep(NA,nAhead)),mod)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Good idea, and it basically works. I suspect that there's a tradeoff of some sort -- otherwise the `dlm` folks could simply use that solution to code `dlmForecast` -- but it does basically work.

Comment: How do I get updated forecast for dlmModReg with new data?
If I re-run dlmFilter, it will re-estimate my model parameters.